# unable to read cookie javascript

Tags: java, javascript, cookies, response

I am setting cookie server-side, using java code

```
response.addCookie("test1","test1");
```

I found this code to retrieve cookie using javascript

```
(function(){
    var cookies;

    function readCookie(name,c,C,i){
        if(cookies){ alert("all cookies"+cookies); return cookies[name]; }

        c = document.cookie.split('; ');
        cookies = {};

        for(i=c.length-1; i>=0; i--){
           C = c[i].split('=');
           cookies[C[0]] = C[1];
        }
        alert("required cookie"+cookies[name]);
        return cookies[name];
    }

    window.readCookie = readCookie; // or expose it however you want
})();
```

I am calling this function as

```
alert(readCookie('test1'));
```

but every time I get the alert as undefined.. 
I checked the chrome's cookie file and my cookie is set there as

```
localhosttest1test1/service/login
```

Can someone explain why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you get the alerts that are called from `readCookie`? What do they show?

Comment: alert("all cookies"+cookies); - shows the alert contents as [object] [object]

alert("required cookie"+cookies[name]); - shows nothing except the string message that I gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to work (I tested it in Firefox, Chrome and MSIE, by creating some cookie with JavaScript, e.g., `document.cookie = "test1=bla"`, and it displays "required cookiebla"). Maybe the cookie you set from the server is marked as `HttpOnly`, so that JavaScript has no access to it?

Comment: so how can I correct that.. I have shown in the beginning of my question that how am I setting the cookie

Comment: one thing before trying to look further, could you try an alert(document.cookie) to display *all* document cookies and see if yours is present?

Comment: but this alert,i.e alert("all cookies"+cookies); in the read cookie function showed [object] [object] as output that means it was reading something

Comment: Not really, as `cookies` is an array, converting it to a string to display it in the alert (independently whether it is empty or not) will display `[object]`. Ok, so the browser cookie array is empty. Now, test if the problem comes from the HTTP cookie, create one locally with JavaScript before calling your function, i.e., with `document.cookie = "test1=somestring";` and see if your function displays the "somestring".

Comment: both are undefined.. alert(window.cookie); and alert(readCookie('test1'));

Comment: did you try `document.cookie` or `window.cookie`? The right one is with `document`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I submitted a link that went to a different path.  i.e., the page I was clicking the link was `/pathOne/somePlace`, but the link went to `/pathTwo/someOtherPlace`.  The cookie that was written was only valid on `/pathTwo/*`.  To correct for this I did :

```
Cookie testCookie = new Cookie("test1","test1");
testCookie.setPath (request.getContextPath ());
response.addCookie (testCookie);
```

hope that helps.